# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'insertAdjacentHTML') at new Poll

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, frontend, backend

I'm checking the chrome console if it is working... it should return "root: div.poll"
instead, it returns "root: null"[have attached a screenShot]

`Poll {root: null, selected: 'JavaScript', endpoint: 'http://localhost:3000/poll'} endpoint: "http://localhost:3000/poll" root: null selected: "JavaScript" [[Prototype]]: Object`

since it is a null value
`

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'insertAdjacentHTML')
    at new Poll (main.js:6:19)
    at main.js:12:11
```

`
it couldn't read that property...

THIS is the main.js file:`

```
class Poll {
    constructor(root, title) {
        this.root = root;
        this.selected = sessionStorage.getItem("poll-selected");
        this.endpoint = "http://localhost:3000/poll";
        this.root.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", `
            <div class="poll__title">${ title }</div>
        `);
    }
}

const p = new Poll(
    document.querySelector(".poll"),
    "Which do you prefer?"
);

console.log(p);
```

`

THIS is the HTML div block im trying to return:`

```
 <div class="poll">
        <div class="poll__title">Which do u prefer?</div>
        <div class="poll__option">
            <div class="poll__option-fill"></div>
            <div class="poll__option-info">
                    <span class="poll__label">TypeScript</span>
                    <span class="poll__percentage">21%</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="poll__option poll__option--selected">
            <div class="poll__option-fill"></div>
            <div class="poll__option-info">
                <span class="poll__label">JavaScript</span>
                <span class="poll__percentage">41%</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

`

I'm trying to update the "root" value as div.poll
instead I'm getting "root: null"
[root value is returning null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBtZR.png)

Comment: Is your `<script>` _above_ your HTML with no `defer` attribute and no `DOMContentLoaded` or `load` listener and is not `type="module"`? See [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as `getElementById` not find the element?](/q/14028959/4642212). The current best practice is to include your JavaScript code as a [module](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) using `<script type="module" src="main.js"></script>` which solves this problem and many more.

Comment: Thank You !...  adding defer in <script> solved the issue